# italic identifiers with Greek letters and Arabic digits with unicode-math

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, greek, italic, slanted

We try to produce an identifier *1* in math mode, i.e., both symbols should be italics or slanted and the distance between the two symbols should be a usual inter-letter distance in a word.  In `[pdf]latex` you'd simply write `\(\mathit{\sigma1}\)`.  What to do with `{xe|lua}latex`?  The only way we were able to generate both letters slanted or italics is via `\(\sigma\mathit{1}\)`, but then I presume that the spacing between the two symbols corresponds to that of multiplication:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
\(\sigma 1\) \(\sigma\mathit{1}\)
\end{document}
```

yields 1 followed by  *1*.

Comment: With `\sigma\mathit{1}` in pdflatex the space in between is wider than with lualatex.

Answer (score 5):

Unicode does not have slanted math digits, so you need a text font with Greek.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
 \(\textit{σ1} + 1\)
\end{document}
```

Comment: But the spacing is wider than desired.  See the left-hand image in the original question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton there are lots of fonts to choose from...

Answer (score 5):

You could also manually define your own `\text...` command and its font(face).

[image: textgrit]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfontface{\textgrit}{Noto Serif italic}
\begin{document}
 \(\textgrit{σ1} + 1\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

First a test.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifluatex
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi

\begin{document}

\(\sigma\mathit{1}\)
\showoutput

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `lualatex` gives

[image]

```
....\mathon
....\TU/latinmodern-math.otf(1)/m/n/10 
....\TU/lmr/m/it/10 1
....\mathoff
```

Compiling with `pdflatex` gives

[image]

```
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^[
....\kern0.35878
....\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 1
....\kern1.35556
....\mathoff
```

As you see, there is no kerning at all between sigma and the digit in LuaLaTeX.

---

You can't use `\mathit{\sigma 1}` with `unicode-math` and it just works by accident with `pdflatex` because of how mathcodes are set up.

Why are you “seeing” too much space? Because the bounding box of “1” is the same width as the other digits, but 1 is narrower. You may want to choose proportional width for the digits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfontface{\mathit}{LMRoman10-Italic}[Numbers=Proportional]

\begin{document}

\(\sigma\mathit{1}\)

\(\sigma\mathit{2}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]